# Representing The Matrix Of A Quadratic Form

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

> For the following Quadratic Form :
>
> $$Q(X)=x_1^2-6x_1x_2+9x_2^2$$
>
> Represent the quadratic form using a matrix

I know that $B(u,v)=\frac{1}{4}[Q(u+v)-Q(u-v)]$ iff $B$ is symmetric

How can I use this formula to find $B$?

Or I can use the fact that $ax_1^2+bx_2^2+2cx_1x_2+dx_1+ex_2+f=0$ can be written as

$\begin{pmatrix} 
  x_1    & x_2 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  a   & c\\
c & b
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  x_1  \\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 
  d    & e
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  x_1  \\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix}+f=0$

So the matrix is just \begin{pmatrix} 
  1   & -3\\
-3 & 9
\end{pmatrix}?

Comment: Yes, indeed. ;)

Comment: Take half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives.